# how to use converter object's value in angularjs controllers

Tags: angularjs, object, converters, hijri

i have below controller in my angularjs controllers

```
.controller('taskCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getRef = function () {
       return getTask();
    };

    $scope.save = function () {
          $.extend(true, getTask(), $scope.data);
    };
}])
```

and my template :

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <label class="ngTemplateTitle" > create Date</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control" id="data.creationDate" type="text"ng-model="data.creationDate"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

i need to convert and view gregorian date to hijri in form.
then after object's value modified by user convert hijri to gregorian date.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) ?

You can import it to your project (very light file), and implement an angular filter for parsing it the way you want...

something like:

```
angular.module('myFilters').filter('formatDateExample', function() {
var defaultFormat = "l";
return function(timestamp, format) {
    format = format || defaultFormat;
    return timestamp ? moment(new Date(timestamp)).format(format) : null;
    // when you'll call the filter from the HTML, it will parse it to gregorian date
};
```

});

in the html template:

```
<div>{{myDateVar | formatDateExample }}</div>
```

or with a custom format directly from the HTML:

```
<div>{{myDateVar | formatDateExample: "DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM" }}</div>
```

The idea is to **keep your date saved in the model in the same way** and only when you want to show it in your view, **parse** it using the filter.